# htaccess permanent redirect index php to root

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using magento and all my urls contains index.php.
Can anyone give me the code to remove index.php

My url looks like this

example.com/index.php/hi-how-are-you.html

I want it redirect to

example.com/hi-how-are-you.html

I want if anyone accessed the page using index.php it should redirect to non index.php url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed time and again in the Magento forums, see e.g. [this thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22199/).

---

To redirect visitors from `/index.php/path` to `/path` you can use the following mod_rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

---

To exclude the admin area, add the following condition before (!) the RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This tells `mod_rewrite` not (`!`) to rewrite if the request begins (`^`) with `/index.php/admin`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Yes i have mod rewrite enabled. And its working. But my problem is people also can access the page with this url example.com/index.php/hi-how-are-you.html I just want them to redirect to example.com/hi-how-are-you.html I don't want to have two urls for a page. Thanks

Comment: @user1091558 Okay, I think I misunderstood you. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could you please tell tell how to make exception for admin pages? I mean example.com/index.php/admin/hi-how-are-you.html I want these kind of url exactly as it is. Because its causing problem in the admin area.

Comment: Thank you! that worked perfectly. Note that you should use the symbol ' instead of ´ `RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)' $1 [R=301,QSA,L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/ using 1.5.1`